# Grunt watch not running tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, less

I'm trying to run a grunt server with livereload and less.
on `grunt less` it does compile my less file but when changing a less file all i get is

```
>> File "app\style\componenets\components.less" changed.
```

I also tried less:development but still no luck.
Btw I get livereload on EVERY file I change, though in the watch task I've only configured less locations..

Thanks in advance!

```
'use strict';

// Gruntfile with the configuration of grunt-express and grunt-open. No livereload yet!
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Load Grunt tasks declared in the package.json file
    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    console.log(__dirname + '\\app\\');

    // Configure Grunt 
    grunt.initConfig({

        // grunt-express will serve the files from the folders listed in `bases`
        // on specified `port` and `hostname`
        express: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    bases: ['app'],
                    port: 8080,
                    hostname: "0.0.0.0",
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },
        less: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    compress: true,
                    yuicompress: true
                },
                files: {
                    // target.css file: source.less file
                    "app/main.css": "app/style/main.less"
                }
            }
        },
        // grunt-watch will monitor the projects files
        watch: {
            less: {
                files: ['<%= express.all.options.base%>/style/*.less', '<%= express.all.options.base%>/style/componenets/*.less'],
                tasks: ['less']
            }
        },

        // grunt-open will open your browser at the project's URL
        open: {
            all: {
                // Gets the port from the connect configuration
                path: 'http://localhost:<%= express.all.options.port%>/#/'
            }
        }

    });

    // Creates the `server` task
    grunt.registerTask('server', [
        'express',
        'open',
        'watch'
    ])

    // Creates the `less` task
    grunt.registerTask('less', ['less']);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

why the alias task at the end of your gruntfile?

```
// Creates the `less` task
grunt.registerTask('less', ['less']);
```

your less task is already defined through your config! remove that line, and you're probably good...

edit: there is at least 1 typo in your less config:

wrong:

<%= express.all.options.base %>/style/*.less'

correct:

<%= express.all.options.bases %>/style/*.less'

Comment: see my edit. make sure, that your paths and so on are set correctly!